# text to fade in after background transition completed

Tags: javascript, html, css

My background has image with transition. The text has to fade in after the background transition completed. I used transition-delay but it works in mozilla and not in chrome. As for the fade in effect, it works in chrome and not in mozzila. Now all I want is the text to fade in after delay.How to correct my code to achieve this pls?

css

```
.text2
{
    margin-top:10%;
    margin-left:0;
    padding-left:0;


    /*fade in effect*/
     transition-delay: 2s;
    -moz-transition-delay:2s;
    -o-transition-delay:2s;
    -webkit-transition-delay:2s;
     animation: fadein 2s;
    -moz-animation: fadein 2s; /* Firefox */
    -webkit-animation: fadein 2s; /* Safari and Chrome */
    -o-animation: fadein 2s; /* Opera */
}

@keyframes fadein {
    from {
        opacity:0;
    }
    to {
        opacity:1;
    }
}
@-moz-keyframes fadein { /* Firefox */
    from {
        opacity:0;
    }
    to {
        opacity:1;
    }
}
@-webkit-keyframes fadein { /* Safari and Chrome */
    from {
        opacity:0;
    }
    to {
        opacity:1;
    }
}
@-o-keyframes fadein { /* Opera */
    from {
        opacity:0;
    }
    to {
        opacity: 1;
    }
}

#target {
    position: relative;
    left:0;
    background-image:url('../img/top-bg.jpg');background-repeat:no-repeat;
     width: 120%;

    background-size:cover;
     height: 600px;  
    background-position: 200px 50%;
  transition: background-position 2s ease-in-out;

}


#target.wide{
    left: -20%;
    padding-left: 30%;
   background-position: 0px 50%;

}
```

script

```
<script>

  $(document).ready(function () {

        $('#target').toggleClass("wide");

});

  </script>
```

html

```
    <div id="target">
        <div class="small-12 medium-11 large-11 columns text2">
                 Beyond Law,<br/>
                 The Spirit of Innovation is Our strenght.
                 </div>
    </div>


</div>

<div style="clear: both"></div>
```

Link:

http://vani.valse.com.my/beldon/index.php

EDITED

```
text2
{
    margin-top:10%;
    margin-left:0;
    padding-left:0;


    /*fade in effect*/
    **transition: opacity 0.5s ease-in;**
     animation: fadein 2s;
    -moz-animation: fadein 2s; /* Firefox */
    -webkit-animation: fadein 2s; /* Safari and Chrome */
    -o-animation: fadein 2s; /* Opera */

   transition-delay: 2s;
    -moz-transition-delay:2s;
    -o-transition-delay:2s;
    -webkit-transition-delay:2s;
}
```

added the line in bold. It works as desired in mozilla but in chrome the transition delay not working.

Comment: Just a quick note, `Strenght.` should be `Strength.` and also, have you tried adding `-webkit-transition-delay` or `-moz-transition-delay` ? You should read [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transition-delay) article about it.

Comment: @daren thanks for the correction. And yes I used -webkit-transition-delay

Comment: Apologies, just read the css code.

Answer (score 0):

I added below lines after the animation as below and got it working in chrome.

```
-webkit-animation-delay: 4s; /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
  /*to make the text not visible untill the transition starts*/
   -webkit-opacity: 0;
   /*without this the text will disappear after the animation*/
    -webkit-animation-fill-mode: forwards;
```

so it should look like this in full

```
.text2
{
    margin-top:10%;
    margin-left:0;
    padding-left:0;


    /*fade in effect*/
     transition: opacity 0.5s ease-in;
    -webkit-transition: opacity 0.5s ease-in;
    -moz-transition: opacity 0.5s ease-in;
    -o-transition: opacity 0.5s ease-in;

     animation: fadein 4s;
    -moz-animation: fadein 4s; /* Firefox */
   -webkit-animation: fadein 4s; /* Safari and Chrome */
    -o-animation: fadein 4s; /* Opera */

     transition-delay: 4s;
    -moz-transition-delay:4s;
    -o-transition-delay:4s;
    -webkit-transition-delay:4s;

   -webkit-animation-delay: 4s; /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
  /*to make the text not visible untill the transition starts*/
   -webkit-opacity: 0;
   /*without this the text will disappear after the animation*/
    -webkit-animation-fill-mode: forwards;

}

@keyframes fadein {
    from {
        opacity:0;
    }
    to {
        opacity:1;
    }
}
@-moz-keyframes fadein { /* Firefox */
    from {
        opacity:0;
    }
    to {
        opacity:1;
    }
}
@-webkit-keyframes fadein { /* Safari and Chrome */
    from {
        opacity:0;
    }
    to {
        opacity:1;
    }
}
@-o-keyframes fadein { /* Opera */
    from {
        opacity:0;
    }
    to {
        opacity: 1;
    }
}
```